# Javascript - Array push for AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, autocomplete, array-push

I am working on a AutoComplete search bar that reads from an array. I am needing to parse a JSON file and push the names into an array. I have everything working except for the right command to push to the actual array. What would I use to push to the array below?

```
    $("#schoolLocal").autocompleteArray(
    [],
    {
        delay:10,
        minChars:1,
        matchSubset:1,
        onItemSelect:selectItem,
        onFindValue:findValue,
        autoFill:true,
        maxItemsToShow:10
    }
);
```

I used 
    $("#schoolLocal").autocompleteArray.push(name);

And of course that didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a standard library's autocomplete functionality like [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery Autocomplete?

Comment: Are you using this library - http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm, or is it your own jQuery plugin that has the `autocompleteArray` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is autoCompleteArray? an array or a function?

Assuming it's an array then:

```
// declare the array  with 2 sub arrays,1 for names and other for definitions (?)
$("#schoolLocal").autocompleteArray = new Array(new Array(),{
        delay:10,
        minChars:1,
        matchSubset:1,
        onItemSelect:selectItem,
        onFindValue:findValue,
        autoFill:true,
        maxItemsToShow:10
    }
);

//push to the names array
$("#schoolLocal").autocompleteArray[0].push(name);
```